# How to use revtex4-2 with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: latex

I've installed `texlive-publishers`; but, still I'm getting the error in kile: `file revtex4-2.cls not found` on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS system.

How to use `revtex4-2` with Ubuntu?

Comment: The `texlive-publishers` package for 18.04 appears to contain `revtex4.cls` and `revtex4-1.cls` - if you need `revtex4-2.cls` you will need to install it manually from [the APS website](https://journals.aps.org/revtex) I think

Comment: thank you for your response sir..I followed the APS instruction: "To install REVTeX 4.2, unzip the revtex4-2-tds.zip file. This zip file contains all of the files in the REVTeX 4.2 distribution in the standard “TeX Directory Structure” (TDS) layout. The files can be copied directly in the local tree of your TeX distribution (for TeX Live, this would be in the texmf-local directory).".. I copied the extracted folder in the directory: usr/share/texmf..& also in usr/local/share/texmf..but still getting the same error..am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try copying the `.cls` file directly into the directory containing your `.tex` document

Comment: that didn't work but then I copied all the remaining files from the same folder (which contains .cls file) into the current directory and it worked...thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

From the [CTAN website](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/revtex4-1), the procedure for installing revtex4-1 in TeXLive 2018 (also works for 4.2) is as follows:

The following method works if you have installed TexLive distributions from the **installer**, and **not** from official Ubuntu repositories.

1. Download the revtex4-2 archive anywhere.
2. Run this command to unzip the archive in the appropriate place:

   `sudo unzip revtex4-1-tds.zip -d /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`
3. Update the TexLive distribution with:

   `sudo mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`

The following method works if you have installed TexLive distributions from the **official Ubuntu repositories**.

1. Download the revtex4-2 archive anywhere.
2. Run this command to unzip the archive in the appropriate place:

   `sudo unzip revtex4-1-tds.zip -d /usr/local/share/texmf`
3. Update the TexLive distribution with:

   `sudo mktexlsr /usr/local/share/texmf`

Now, if you open a revtex template in an appropriate editor (kile, texstudio etc.) it should work without a problem.

Comment: If TeXLive was installed from the repositories, the correct directory appears to be
`/usr/local/share/texmf`, as found from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94650/189341) on stackexchange. This works on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation at least, while the directory you suggested does not.

Comment: ok that is interesting. I have installed my texlive distribution using the installer and not from the repositories so my path is the one in my answer. Nice catch!

Comment: Thanks.
Should I extract the whole folder to /usr/local/share/texmf ? It contains pdf files so I feel indecisive.

Comment: This answer does not work on Ubuntu 22.04 for installed texlive-latex-base and texlive-latex-extra! Still cannot find revtex...